# Label Volue doesnt change it all same with 1st volue in php

Tags: php, html

I beginner

I connect my database and I get problem, my label volue are same with 1st volue. I dont know how to fix

PS : My English is terrible

````
                while($pv_array=$res_pv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
    $j++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?=$j?></td>
                <td><?=$pv_array['U_ID']?></td>
                <td><?=$pv_array['U_NAME']?></td>
                <td><?=$pv_array['U_PASSWORD']?></td>
                <td><?=$pv_array['U_EMAIL']?></td>
                <td><?=$pv_array['U_LEVEL']?></td>
   
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-bs-target="#showForm" data-bs-toggle="modal">Edit</button></td>
    <div class="from-group">
                                    <label>User ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$pv_array['U_ID']?>">
                                <div class="from-group">
                                  <label>User Name</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$pv_array['U_NAME']?>">
                              </div>
                              <div class="from-group">
                                  <label>User_Password</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$pv_array['U_PASSWORD']?>">
                              </div>
                              <div class="from-group">
                                  <label>User_Email</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$pv_array['U_EMAIL']?>">
                              </div>
            
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                                  <button class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
    }
               ```
````

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You fail to close the table-row, you cannot add `div` elements at the location within the table that you have here, a `label` must be associated with an input element (either using ID or by encasing it )and there is a `div` also unclosed

Comment: `input` elements most usually need a `name` to make sense when the form they are in (presumably they are within a form) is submitted. Incidentally `labels` themselves do not have a `value`  - they have textContent